# Redirect www to non-www and http to https in one redirect?

Tags: haproxy

I've been trying to get this to work, but cannot.

I know I can redirect http -> https using something like this:

```
http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

I know I can redirect www -> non-www using something like this:

```
http-request redirect prefix https://%[hdr(host)] code 301 if { hdr_beg(host) -i www } 
// although note this doesn't work for me, it does nothing
```

I need the following:

```
http://example.com/any-uri      -> https://example.com/any-uri
http://www.example.com/any-uri  -> https://example.com/any-uri
https://www.example.com/any-uri -> https://example.com/any-uri
```

How can I do both http -> https and www -> non-www using a single 301 redirect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, although it requires two rules.

```
http-request redirect prefix https://%[hdr(host),regsub(^www\.,,i)] code 301 if { hdr_beg(host) -i www. }
http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

Based on the above, the following will happen, all with a single redirect:

```
http://example.com/any-uri      -> https://example.com/any-uri
http://www.example.com/any-uri  -> https://example.com/any-uri
https://www.example.com/any-uri -> https://example.com/any-uri
```

This is because the first rule catches `http://www...` and `https://www...` URLs and redirects them to `https://example.com`. The remaining case is `http://example.com` which gets handled by the second rule via a simple redirect to `https://example.com`.

Comment: add `or !{ ssl_fc }` to first line and see if that works in one rule